# Apache solr 5.3 single instance for live site

Tags: solr

We are going to develop a website having 200000 documents. Could We go for solr5.5 single instance as a no sql database? Please guide me.

Thanks,
Srilakshmi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the solr for your application without any problem.

There are other very good features of solr which will help you like sharding,replication etc..

These features will help you to achieve good results for your application irrespective of how big your application growth.

You can also consider other systems like mongodb as well.

Comment: @srilu: If this answer works for you could you please accept or vote :)